# What perk effects work on off-perk weapons?

Tags: killing-floor

Sometimes you want to be a little naughty and want to use weapons that aren't your perk weapons - maybe your sharpshooter really fancies that flare revolver or the scope on that SCAR, or perhaps your commando thinks it would be a good idea to have a medic gun handy. What perk effects, if any, work on off-perk weapons?

Comment: I don't actually know of weapon bonuses that work on off-perk weapons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Support Specialist's penetration bonus works on the Dragon's Breath Trenchgun. This is the only perk bonus I'm aware of that works on an off-perk weapon.